# Processing: Rendering stops when delay function used

Tags: processing

I created a simple delay function for my sketch and tried to use it, but it seems as if the rendering stops i.e., there is simple a grey screen and then everything is rendered all at once. 
Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong? What exactly is happening?
Also how are draw() and setup() defined internally? I understand that setup() is a one time render and draw() like an infinite loop.

Code:

```
void delay(int delay)
{
int time = millis();
while(millis() - time <= delay);
}

void setup(){
   size(600,400);
   smooth();     
 }

void draw(){
   background(0); //black
   delay(1000);
   fill(255); //white
   ellipse(width/2, height/2, 300, 300);
   delay(1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also how are draw() and setup() defined internally? I understand that setup() is a one time render >and draw() like an infinite loop.

The thing is that draw() only renders a frame at the end of each execution, so stoping it is usually not a good idea.

http://wiki.processing.org/w/I_display_images_in_sequence_but_I_see_only_the_last_one._Why%3F

If you want to time things use booleans as flags for when things should happen.

check those also:

[http://wiki.processing.org/w/What_are_setup()_and_draw()%3F](http://wiki.processing.org/w/What_are_setup%28%29_and_draw%28%29%3F)

http://wiki.processing.org/w/How_do_I_display_a_message_for_a_few_seconds%3F

Answer (score 0):

If you want delay, use a Thread() object, like the following code, to run the delays in a separate thread:

```
void delay(int delay)
{
  try
  {
  Thread.sleep(delay);
  }
  catch(Exception EX)
  {
  }
}

void setup(){
   size(600,400);
   smooth();
   thread("sleepy"); // the function sleepy will be started in a new thread     
 }

void draw(){
 // draw() does nothing here except refresh the screen
 }
void sleepy()
{
  while(true)
  {
    background(0); //black
    delay(1000);
    fill(255); //white
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, 300, 300);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Additionally, the above delay method, Thread.sleep(), does not consume an entire CPU core as it runs (The millis() method is akin to a temporary infinite loop).
Tested on Processing 2.2.1, Windows 7 professional.